# Allow empty identity in git repository

Tags: git

I have created a git repository with `git init`, and when someone pulls something from it they get this message:

```
someone@somewhere:~/$ git pull

*** Please tell me who you are.

Run

  git config --global user.email "you@example.com"
  git config --global user.name "Your Name"

to set your account's default identity.
Omit --global to set the identity only in this repository.

fatal: empty ident  <> not allowed
```

I can force each user to fill dummy ident; however this is my repo so can I allow for empty ident?

Comment: The error message you're getting is about your own identity, not that of users who pull from your repo. You need to set your identity as explained in the message.

Comment: You are wrong, this is message what every anonymous user get when do 'git pull'. I don't need to know who pull or push code to this repo so can I just ignore ident and stop make unnecessary problem.

Comment: Let me clarify: the onus is on whoever is pulling from your repo to set up their Git identity, not on you. This error message that others are getting shouldn't bother you; it's their problem, not yours.

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't.

The identity information shown here is used on each and every git commit that you do (in the form of `GIT_COMMITTER_EMAIL` and `GIT_AUTHOR_EMAIL`) and so they are a fundamental property of any commits that you will do. Anyone who pulls changes from you will have see those names; similarly, if you receive contributions from anyone then you will see those details as well.

If you never want to commit (which can happen when you do a `git pull`) then you don't need to provide these, but if you ever want to commit into the repository then you will need to supply them.

Answer (score 0):

You write

> I can force each user to fill dummy ident; however this is my repo so can I allow for empty ident?

You seem to misunderstand that individual Git users are supposed to set up their Git identity themselves.

Whoever pulls from your repo and gets that error message simply needs to to set up their Git identity. It's *their responsibility* to set up Git properly on their machine, *not yours*. This initial setup has nothing to do with any particular repo, yours or any other.

Besides, there is nothing you can do on your end to automate the setup of their Git identity.

See the [relevant section of the Pro Git book](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Getting-Started-First-Time-Git-Setup#Your-Identity) for an explanation of the Git identity.